# Excel VBA in Outlook Appointment - Replace function strips formatting

Tags: vba, excel, outlook, macros

I am trying to write a macro that sends a placeholder from Excel to Outlook Calendar using an .oft **appointment** template.

When using the replace function like that:

```
Dim oMail as Object
Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set oMail = myOlApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(path)
```

(...)

```
strFind = "Value"
strNew = Cells(x ,y)
oMail.body = Replace (oMail.body, strFind, strNew)
```

Appointment comes out as plaintext, all formatting is stripped. Fonts, links and even the signature.

If I change the value .body to .HTMLbody, the replace function does not work, template comes out unedited. I do not want to put in the emails content as body into code as they change sometimes and that would make me edit the macro every time instead of the template.

Any suggestions, please?
I ran out of ideas.

Comment: Copy everything into an empty word document first and then do the replacement in the word document. Once you are done, you can copy the content over to Outlook.

Comment: That is a good workaround, thank you. However I would rather solve this problem as it seems that I am defining something wrong than proceed straight to workarounds. If there is no other solution, I will use that.

Comment: Let me know if you find anything. I'd be interested too. I have seen this question (in other forms) many times before and each time the solution was to use MS Word. If you'd find something new I'd be very surprised and interested.

Comment: @Ralph I will try the RTFBody thing below tomorrow but so far I got around using Word by simply splitting that. First I do the body in an email, then set all appointment details and then manually copy contents from email to appointment. It is much faster and more convenient than Word as it does not require to open another program. Manual step also helps with data validation.

Answer (score 0):

The body property of oMail  is plain text. 
RTFbody has all the formatting but it is a byte array

```
Dim oMail as Outlook.AppointmentItem
Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set oMail = myOlApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(path)

 Dim RegulareString As String

'convert from byte array to a string
 RegulareString = StrConv(pushAppt.RTFBody, vbUnicode)

'do your replacements
RegulareString = Replace(RegulareString , strFind, strNew)

'convert back to byte array
Dim theBytes() As Byte
theBytes = StrConv(RegulareString , vbFromUnicode)

oMail.RTFBody = theBytes
oMail.Display
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for that, I will check it tomorrow!